# Firefox crashes after update to 112.02

Tags: 22.04, firefox

Platform Ubuntu 22.04-2.

After update (`sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`) of the OS (including FF), Firefox started briefly, but within a minute it crashes.
Using `firefox --safe-mode` did not help.
Then I ran Forefox from a terminal.

```
 firefox 2>&1 | tee ~/Downloads/ff.log
[ERROR glean_core] Error setting metrics feature config: Json(Error("EOF while parsing a value", line: 1, column: 0))
ExceptionHandler::GenerateDump cloned child 4460
ExceptionHandler::SendContinueSignalToChild sent continue signal to child
ExceptionHandler::WaitForContinueSignal waiting for continue signal...
Exiting due to channel error.
Exiting due to channel error.
Exiting due to channel error.
Exiting due to channel error.
Exiting due to channel error.
Exiting due to channel error.
Exiting due to channel error.
Failed to open curl lib from binary, use libcurl.so instead
```

It appears some libraries are not working.

The same Firefox runs flawlessly on another Ubuntu (20.04-7 LTS ARM) and on macOS Ventura.
I tried uninstalling, reinstalling and rebooting to no avail.

Any ideas on this ?

Comment: deb flatpak or snap version of FF? [edit] into your question

Comment: Does not help. Removed with `snap remove firefox`, then `snap install firefox` removed profile and removed add-ons and same issue. "json(Error("EOF while parsing a value".

Comment: am I missing something here? You say you used apt commands in your question (suggesting the deb version) but then comment about the snap version.

Comment: I first use apt commands and later on I uninstalled and reinstalled it with snap.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies, wanted to make this a comment, but don't have the rep points

You said,

> "Removed with snap remove firefox, then snap install
> firefox removed profile and removed add-ons"

Have you tried uninstalling using `sudo apt remove firefox`?
Also you may want to try `sudo snap refresh` as well after your installation.

Ta!